# I need to get a value for handling_fee and handling_type from magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to pull the configuration data from Magento in order to perform some front end calculations. For some reason the tabled rates handling fee is proving difficult.

I need to pull these values from core_config_data

```
(1,'default',0,'carriers/tablerate/handling_type','P'),
(2,'default',0,'carriers/tablerate/handling_fee','18.5'),
```

I've tried each of these (separately):

```
$handlingFee = Mage::getModel('shipping/carriers/tablerate')->getHandlingFee();
$handlingFee = Mage::getModel('shipping/carriers')->getHandlingFee();
$handlingFee = Mage::getModel('carriers/tablerate')->getHandlingFee();
```

I also tried these(based on a model I saw referencing the values I need:

```
$handlingFee = Mage::getModel('shipping/carriers/tablerate')->getConfigData('handling_fee');
$handlingFee = Mage::getModel('shipping/carriers')->getConfigData('handling_fee');
$handlingFee = Mage::getModel('carriers/tablerate')->getConfigData('handling_fee');
```

Followed by an:

```
echo $handlingFee;
```

I'm still working on understanding how to traverse Magento. What am I missing? I've been able to pull from some of the other tables just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `core_config_data` table is a special table that doesn't work like Magento's other CRUD datastores.  The way to pull data from this table is with

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/tablerate/handling_type', $store_id);
```

where `$store_id` is equal to the numeric ID of a store view.  Re: the `$store_id`, you set data in this table on the backend in the `System -> Configuration` section — this UI allows you to set different values for different stores.  That's why `getStoreConfig` accepts a store id paramater.  If you omit it

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/tablerate/handling_type');
```

Magento will select the value for the current store ID.  You can also get an array of data with

```
$array = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/tablerate');
var_dump($array);
```

If you **really** want to jump down the rabbit hole (which you don't need to) — you're not actually reading data from this table when you use the above static method calls.  These configuration values are stored in Magento's global XML configuration tree, and when Magento loads this tree it merges values from the `core_config_data` table into the main configuration tree.  The details are too long for a single Stack Overflow question, but if you're interested in that sort of deep nerd-ery [this series of articles](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_config) (self-link) will explain how these values are actually loaded.

Comment: Thanks! funny enough, I figured this out a shortly before you answered by continuing to refine my Google searches over a couple hours. I wish I had more up votes to give. That's exactly the kind of nerd-ery I'm looking for. Typically I send this to my developers. In this case I'm trying to get a better understanding myself.